# SQL - Updating specific rows based on group by count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update a set of rows if they fall within the result of a group by + having criteria:

Example Table:

```
equip_id | fiber_id | new_col
-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
A        | 1        | *update this row/col because there are (3) A's
A        | 2        | *update this row/col because there are (3) A's
A        | 3        | *update this row/col because there are (3) A's
B        | 1        | *dont update this row/col because there are (4) B's
B        | 2        | *dont update this row/col because there are (4) B's
B        | 3        | *dont update this row/col because there are (4) B's
B        | 4        | *dont update this row/col because there are (4) B's
```

I want to update new_col only where GROUP BY equip_id HAVING count(equip_id) = 3

Since GROUP BY is not supported in UPDATE, how do I achieve this result?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following nested table expression:

```
update table_name
set ...
where equip_id in (
    select equip_id
    from table_name
    group by equip_id
    having count(*) = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is already given by Andronicus.

Below is just another way. Not sure it is more effective.

```
update table_name set new_col=NEW_VALUE
where equip_id in

(
  select equip_id from table_name a
    where 3=
     (
       select count(*) from table_name b where 
       a.equip_id=b.equip_id
     )
)
```